# How to edit the textarea that uses CodeMirror plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codemirror

I have a formatted / beautified text in the textarea (formatted using  CodeMirror). Now I am not able to edit the textarea.

EDIT: 
Here is the html portion Iam using

```
<div class="form-group ">
   <textarea id="alertTemplate" class="form-control" placeholder="Condition " rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
```

Here is the code I am using to convert the textarea content above to formatted javascript using codemirror

```
var editor;
var test = js_beautify(data.condition.script);
    $('#alertTemplate').empty();
    $('#alertTemplate').val(test);
    editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("alertTemplate"),{
                lineNumbers: true,
                theme: "default",
                mode: "javascript",
                readOnly: false
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have no `readOnly: true` in your setting.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var readOnlyCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('codesnippet_readonly'), {
    mode: "javascript",
    theme: "default",
    lineNumbers: true,
    readOnly: true
  });  

  var editableCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('codesnippet_editable'), {
    mode: "javascript",
    theme: "default",
    lineNumbers: true
  });
};
```

```html
<h1>Using CodeMirror (readonly and editable code)</h1>

<p><a href="http://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/index.html">http://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/index.html</a></p>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
<script src="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/edit/matchbrackets.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/edit/continuecomment.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>

<h2>Readonly</h2>        

<div>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="codesnippet_readonly" name="codesnippet_readonly">
    // Demo code (the actual new parser character stream implementation)

  var readOnlyCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('codesnippet_readonly'), {
    mode: "javascript",
    theme: "default",
    lineNumbers: true,
    readOnly: true // This make the textarea readonly
  });
  </textarea>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Editable</h2>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="codesnippet_editable" id="codesnippet_editable">
    // Demo code (the actual new parser character stream implementation)

  var editableCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('codesnippet_editable'), {
    mode: "javascript",
    theme: "default",
    lineNumbers: true
  });
  </textarea>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that you are using? Even better, can you add a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) with this code? In that way I could see the problem a live.

Comment: I didn't know that you updated your question. In the future, let us know by leaving comment. In my [test](http://output.jsbin.com/zetarax) it's working event you set the value dynamically. Can you **create a snippet** with this problem? May you converted the textarea to editor and now you want to update the content or something?